# 5V across SSR from Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, solid-state-relay

i have RaspberryPi, SSR-25 with triac inside.
RaspberryPi GPIOs are 3v3.
It is written that it does work with the voltage from 3V, however 3v3 does not trip the triack - 5V does.

Is it safe for Raspberry,
to connect both 3v3 and 5v across DC side of this SSR, 
and turn GPIO 3v3 OFF, to get 5V across SSR and send it signal further?

I want to make this solution, as simple as possible.

Thanks

Comment: First question: what is the triac switching? I hope it is not mains voltage or is there an opto-coupler in between?

Comment: Full Electronic diagram of the black box you will find here, Solid State Relay || DIY or Buy 07:22 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UtL2uAYCUA
so now when this important question is solved, lets be back to the main question, thank you